# querying with mysql-simple-pool escaping characters

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Im using node.js mysql-simple-pool and I am trying to escape user input. Doing

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', tableData, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(results);
});
```

where `tableData = {name: 'jon', last: 'doe'}` I get `[TypeError: Object #<Pool> has no method 'escape']`. So is there a way around this or do I need to claim the connection to escape the values?

**EDIT**

I just tested claiming the connection and got the same results as mentioned above. Im lost now :D

```
pool.claim(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Claimning connection error: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', tableData, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error inserting job to DB: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Insert results :' + results);
        connection.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after looking at node-mysql, it supports connection pooling. I made the switch and can use .escape() to sanitize data. :D